# Simple MySQL Query Fix

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, sql-update

When in ASP.Net, the Datagrid will update every selected row, except the first column "Event Name".  Any ideas as to why this is happening would be appreciated.  Also, if I implement this query on other tables, will this overwrite the data originally held?

```
 UPDATE  Calendar SET 
    `Event Name`=@`Event Name`,
    `Date`=@Date,
    `Time`=@Date,
    `Location`=@Location,
    `Goal`=@Goal 
WHERE `ID`=@ID
```

Comment: Did you meant to put two spaces in there? Why not just call the parameter @EventName and be done with it.

Comment: I did not mean to put that in there, I will edit that on here.  I will try that now.

Comment: That did not work, the first column Event Name still does not update.

Comment: you are passing your event name variable as @'Event Name' is it need to be @Event Name only

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE  Calendar SET 
    `Event Name`=@Event_Name,
    `Date`=@Date,
    `Time`=@Date,
    `Location`=@Location,
    `Goal`=@Goal 
WHERE `ID`=@ID

No quotes.